# Unexpected synthetic property @flyInOut found. Please make sure that: - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` (angular 12)

Tags: angular

browser console error  ==>  Error: Unexpected synthetic property @flyInOut found. Please make sure that:

- Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.

[image]

**package.json**

```json
   

    
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do what the error suggested you do? Need one of those modules imported.

Comment: @Phix still not working after import the BrowserAnimationsModule . everything working fine before install ngx-toastr

Comment: Can you post the code of where you're importing and where the animation is being implemented?

Comment: @Phix       import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';  //new line=>   insertRecord(form:NgForm){
    console.log("insert data ====>",form.value)
    this.service.postUser().subscribe(
      res =>{
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.service.refreshList();
        this.toastr.success('user added successfully', 'User Detail register')
      console.log("insert data ====>",res)
      },
      err => {console.log(err);}
    )
  }

Comment: No, please _edit your question_ and post the formatted code there. It's not easy to read as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this problem, the solution was to import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` module from `"@angular/platform-browser/animations"` to the `AppModule`

```js
...
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced this issue in angular 17 project and then added the 'provideAnimations' in the provider section in app.config.ts file.

```
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideToastr(),
    provideAnimations(),
  ],
};

Now the issue has been resolved.
```

Answer (score 0):

In main.ts make sure you add the animations in the providers

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideAnimations()],
});
```